# Angular model was not updated for inner property of an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a model object "o" below that refer to another scope property, testText. I would expect that when $scope.testText get updated,     $scope.o.filed1 will get updated automatically.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['kendo.directives']); 
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($compile, $scope) {
$scope.o={};
$scope.testText = 'hello';
$scope.o.filed1 = $scope.testText;
```

But it doesn't work as I expected. Here is my online sample.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZHS8EdcCb5EJwQ8UUenj?p=preview

Comment: $scope.o.filed1 = $scope.testText, makes a copy of the testText value at runtime and is now it's own  value, it doesn't 'watch' it for changes

Comment: Just note that this should never be necessary. It's setting up the same value with two different names. It doesn't make any sense. X/Y problem.

Comment: @m59, yes this doesn't make sense. I just try out angular. And thx Rob for telling me that actually the value is copied while not referrenced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this will not work, because it is just an assignment. try this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['kendo.directives']); 

app.controller("myCtrl", function ($compile, $scope) {
   $scope.o={};
   $scope.testText = 'hello';
   $scope.$watch('testText', function(newValue){
      $scope.o.filed1 = newValue;
   });
});
```